# Switching from Powerpoint to Propresenter

Tags: mac, microsoft-powerpoint

quick question for some of you A/V guys. I am having an issue with propresenter and powerpoint. We use propresenter for a majority of our presentations but have to have a powerpoint stuck in there since we have a guy that lives by it. My question is this: does anybody have a macro or similar that will switch from powerpoint back to propresenter after the powerpoint presentation? This is all on a mac, so it needs to be mac or office 2011 friendly. Thanks guys. Hope I can figure this out!